# Действие (sql update) по кнопке в GridView

Tags: php, sql, yii2, gridview

Необходимо по нажатию на галочку напротив строки присваивать ей статус `ready` (поле в бд) и скрывать по тому же фильтру (ready).
Есть sql команда, есть табличка, нужно поменять значение в БД по имени поля, нажимая на кнопку напротив соответствующих значений.

Команда для изменения:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE transactions SET ready=1 WHERE id = ' .$flag)->execute();
```

Табличка с кнопкой:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'value',
        'ready',
        [
            'header' => 'Подтвердить',
            'template' => '{update}',
            'buttons' => [
                'update' => function ($flag???) {
                    return ???
                }
```

Каким образом передать функции нужное значение (id строчки) и как собственно заставить ее записать параметр в табличку по нажатию кнопки?

Либо это надо решать вообще по другому и использовать стандартную кнопку или ссылку и передать ей параметр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов: воспользоваться jQuery

```
'update' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
     return \yii\helpers\Html::a('Update', null,
         ['class' => 'send', 'data-id' => $model->id]);
 },
```

Пример кода javascript

```
$this->registerJs("
    $('.send').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(self).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/<your-action>',
            data: {
                id: id,
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            // your code
        });
    });
");
```

И не забудьте создать в контроллере action указанный в коде, куда поместите

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE transactions SET ready=1 WHERE id = ' .$flag)->execute();
```

Comment: Спасибо, а где именно должен быть js?

Comment: Его можно поместить в любом месте во view. Я обычно помещаю вверху после описание классов с пространствами имён. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals-ru/view-code-style.md (В этом месте "Установка свойств контекста, вызов сеттеров и другие действия.")